# jQuery UI: Loading Dialog While Images are Loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a website made in ASP.NET MVC3 with the Razor rendering view. Within this site I create charts (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart) and serve them as images with a controller to my view.

It can take anywhere from 1 to 5 seconds to load the charts. Therefore, I wish to show a loading modal dialog to give some feedback to the user.

Creating a **jQuery UI dialog** is very simple and I have heard of solutions with a timed closing. Yet, a time delayed close is not a proper solution in my case because the of the time variation.

Is it possible to show a **single loading dialog** until every image on a page is loaded and rendered by a browser? How could I do this?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Separate URL for each image that you can load via jQuery you can hook into the load event and when it's done hide the wait image. Would this approach work for you? If so I'll edit and add code.

Comment: I have a different URL for each chart image. I call an HTTP.Get method in my controller that generates and returns the proper chart image according to a named parameter. For example: http://localhost/GetImg?name=Foo.

Comment: The URL is generated server side though.. so I guess it would have to be dynamic JavaScript?

Comment: check out the code here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234148/jquery-re-establish-img-src-in-load-function   what you want to do is show each wait image, secondly - hook the load event of your images (ie your reports) to some onload method. the 'onload' method you define simply hides your wait images. You want the want the SO question postedup top, not the error function but the load function. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a handler to [Load Event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Add a absolute positioned div over the img (through css) which will show a loading img. Add a load event handler to the img tag which should remove the absolute positioned div when the load event is fired.

Comment: It would have to be relative in my case because my layout is fluid.

Comment: sure, use relative... that wont affect the js

Comment: I have seen this practise in quite a few places like lightbox plugins. eg. ColorBox